# No se guardan los registros en el base de datos de PhpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, html5, phpmyadmin

Este es el codigo de agregar_candidato donde me conecto a base de datos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

     <?php
        require_once 'login.php';
         $conectar  = mysqli_connect($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
           if(!$conectar){
            echo "No conectado";
        }


            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $apellido_paterno = $_POST['apellido_paterno'];
            $apellido_materno = $_POST['apellido_materno'];
            $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
            $colonia = $_POST['colonia'];
            $ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
            $estado = $_POST['estado'];
            $codigo_postal = $_POST['codigo_postal'];
            $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
            $puesto_de_interes = $_POST['puesto_de_interes'];


         $sql  = "INSERT INTO candidatos (id, email, nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, direccion, colonia, ciudad, estado, codigo_postal, telefono, puesto_de_interes) 
           VALUES ('','$email','$nombre','$apellido_paterno','$apellido_materno','$direccion','$colonia','$ciudad','$estado','$codigo_postal','$telefono','$puesto_de_interes')";//query de SQL

            $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql );

                if(!$ejecutar){
                    echo "Error, no se almacenaron los datos.";
                }else{
                    echo "Datos almacenados correctamente";
                }


                mysqli_close($conectar);
                //header( "refresh:1;url=unete.php" );
            ?>
```

Este es el codigo del formulario de archivo unete.php:

```
div class="container-sm p-5 ">
            <form id="unete_form" method="POST" class="needs-validation"  action="agregar_candidato.php" novalidate>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="" id="email"  required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputName">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputLastName1">Apellido Paterno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_paterno"  id="apellido_paterno" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Campo Obligatorio*
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputLastName2">Apellido Materno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_materno" id="apellido_materno" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Campo Obligatorio*
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAddress">Direccion</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Calle/Num.Exterior/Num.Interior" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Campo Obligatorio*
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAddress">Colonia</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="colonia" id="colonia" placeholder="Colonia">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputCity">Ciudad</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Campo Obligatorio*
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputState">Estado</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estado" id="estado" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Campo Obligatorio*
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="inputZip">Codigo Postal</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo_postal" id="codigo_postal" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Campo Obligatorio*
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputPhone1">Telefono</label>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control" id="telefono">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputState">Puesto de interes</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="puesto_de_interes" id="puesto_de_interes" required>
                            <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
                            <option>Mesero</option>
                            <option>Host</option>
                            <option>Cocinero</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Campo Obligatorio*
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center  p-5 ">
                    <button type="submit" id= "submit_form" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg font-weight-bold ">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <div class="p-4">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.
Cuando le doy click en el boton submit me marca el error que no guardaron los datos.

Comment: Has probado a quitarle el campo ID.Por lo que parece es el campo autoincrement . Es así? Es una Primary Key? Le tienes que pasar algun valor?Puedes probar quitandole el campo ID dejando asi la query:
$sql  = "INSERT INTO candidatos ( email, nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, direccion, colonia, ciudad, estado, codigo_postal, telefono, puesto_de_interes) 
           VALUES ('$email','$nombre','$apellido_paterno','$apellido_materno','$direccion','$colonia','$ciudad','$estado','$codigo_postal','$telefono','$puesto_de_interes')";//query de SQ

Comment: El problema era que en mi base de datos tenia esta tabla y otra, pero no habia hecho las relaciones (normalizacion) entre ellas, por eso no se guardaban. El codigo que tengo es correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías darnos más detalle acerca de la tabla a la que estás atacando. Si el campo **id** es autoincremental, deberías eliminarlo del select. La consulta debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO candidatos (email, nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, direccion, colonia, ciudad, estado, codigo_postal, telefono, puesto_de_interes) VALUES ('$email','$nombre','$apellido_paterno','$apellido_materno','$direccion','$colonia','$ciudad','$estado','$codigo_postal','$telefono','$puesto_de_interes')";
```

Comment: Gracias, ese no era mi problema, Pero si tienes toda la razon sobre quitar el id.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de empezar a usar [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Puede que el error sea a la comillas de tu sentencia. 
Prueba:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO candidatos (email, nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, direccion, colonia, ciudad, estado, codigo_postal, telefono, puesto_de_interes) VALUES ('".$email."','".$nombre."','".$apellido_paterno."','".$apellido_materno."','".$direccion."','".$colonia."','".$ciudad."','".$estado."','".$codigo_postal."','".$telefono."','".$puesto_de_interes."')";
```